# Fullscreen & Immersive Sticky mode. Android Studio and LibGDX

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

I am developing a game and I want it to be in **Immersive sticky and Fullscreen mode**, I used the code provided by the web page **Android developers:** https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive?hl=es_419#EnableFullscreen

Now, I implemented the code as follows(AndroidLauncher class):

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        hideSystemUI();
    }
}

private void hideSystemUI() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                    // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    // Hide the navbar and status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

I used Android 9(API level 28) and technically it works, the phone's UI is hidden but there is a black space on top.

[image]
[image]

I want the app to fill the entire screen, but only the bottom part is filled while the top part is empty, I don't want the screen to scale when displaying phone UI.
I am using LibGDX and I don't know if it has something to do.
This is the **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:isGame="true"
    android:appCategory="game"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="arrive.further.game.AndroidLauncher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who haven't stumbled upon it yet, there's a simple way to achieve this in one line of code using the `AndroidApplicationConfiguration` object:

In your `AndroidLauncher` class:

```java
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

        config.useImmersiveMode = true;

        initialize(new YourGame(), config);
    }
}
```